# Cuttlefish.io (Ruby on Rails) configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postfix-mta

I have deployed [Cuttlefish](https://cuttlefish.io/) (Ruby on Rails transactional email App) on my Ubuntu server by following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04).

After visiting **domain.example.com** and logging in to Cuttlefish I click **Test email** then enter my Gmail address in the TO box, then click Send test email.

I get a **Test email sent** message but the email never arrives. I have also tried sending messages by creating an App then try to use the smtp credentials in [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) but I can't connect to the smtp server.

The smtp settings which the app page gives me are as follows:-

```
Protocol: SMTP
Host: localhost
Port: 2525
Username: test_2
Password: xxxxxxx
Authentication: plain
```

When I run **telnet localhost 2525** in terminal I get a connection refused error.

When I run **netstat -anltp|grep :2525** I get no result.

I have postfix installed and working on my server.

Please will you help me to send emails through Cuttlefish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuttlefish has its own smtp server based on EventMachine gem, and it runs on 2525 port. Postfix runs by default on my Ubuntu on 25. So, it seems, that your smtp process not working.

You should export upstart jobs with foreman. To do so, I prefer to use following capistrano task:

```
desc 'Foreman init'
task :foreman_init do
  on roles(:all) do
    foreman_temp = "/var/www/tmp/foreman"
    execute  "mkdir -p #{foreman_temp}"

    execute "ln -s #{release_path} #{current_path}"

    within current_path do
      execute "cd #{current_path}"
      execute :bundle, "exec foreman export upstart #{foreman_temp} -a #{application} -u #{user} -l /var/www/apps/#{application}/log -d #{current_path} -f Procfile.production"
    end
    sudo "mv #{foreman_temp}/* /etc/init/"
    sudo "rm -r #{foreman_temp}"
  end
end
```

Please, note, that there are 3 processes in Cuttlefish's Procfile:

```
smtp: rvm . do bundle exec rake cuttlefish:smtp RAILS_ENV=production
log: rvm . do bundle exec rake cuttlefish:log RAILS_ENV=production
worker: rvm . do bundle exec rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, were you able to finally run Cuttlefish ?

Comment: If I try to send a test email, it gives me an EOFError. I don't know RoR, so any help would be really appreciated